# what's the hotkey to move a loop edge?

Tags: edges, loop

I'm trying to move a loop edge on a sphere to make an eyeball. I'm able to select the loop edge but when I move it the sphere starts to lose shape which is not what I want. how do I move the loop edge across the sphere a tad without changing its shape. someone fill me in please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> called *loop slide*. Click when done. <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> is type the <kbd>G</kbd> key twice.